# MsSQL вывод без повторений

Tags: sql-server

День добрый,

Допусти у меня имеется таблица

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g |

| y | 4 | 2 | f | b | s | p |

| 3 | 9 | s |6 | m | a | v |

| 7 | 4 | 2 | f | m | a | v | - Нужно чтобы эта строка не выводилась

| 7 | 4 | 2 | 2 | m | a | v |

| 7 | 4 | 2 | f | m | a | v |

Мне нужно вывести так чтобы если столбцы c и столбец d соответствуют и другим строкам
то выводилась бы только одна строка

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g |

| y | 4 | 2 | f | b | s | p |

| 3 | 9 | s |6 | m | a | v |

| 7 | 4 | 2 | 2 | m | a | v |

| 7 | 4 | 2 | f | m | a | v |

Подскажите пожалйста как это сделать

Comment: DISTINCT ?

Comment: Не подходит, потому что он убирает те строки которые повторяется полность а не те у которых повроряются только определённые столбцы

Comment: Вы задумывались что делать если :

    | 7 | 4 | 2 | f | m | a | v | - у обоих строк есть повторения в  
    | 1 | 2 | 3 | f | m | с | s | - требуемых столбцах

какую строку выводить, информация то разная ?

Comment: | y | 4 | 2 | f | b | s | p |
| 7 | 4 | 2 | f | m | a | v | - Нужно чтобы эта строка не выводилась

Вот так. Из них выводится только одна строка потому что у обоих строк c = 2 и d = f

Comment: @green93 Которая? Любая или нет?

Comment: @green93 с и d одинаковые, а остальное разное, как выбрать? как Вы хотите что бы выбирало ?

Answer (score 2):

```
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g from
(select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by c,d order by a,b,e,f,g) n  from t) X
where n=1;
```

[Функция row_number](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_row_number_function.html)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
select distinct c,d from table
```

результатом вывода будут только уникальные строки у которых не повторяются **НЕ c или d, а именно c и d**

**UPD:**

Можно еще так :

```
select c,d,max(a),max(b),max(e),max(f),max(g) from orders group by c,d
```

так как у выведенной строки может быть несколько вариаций других столбцов, то требуется выбрать отображать какое то одно из многих значений, например min или max

Comment: и где в этой выборке столбцы a,b,e,f и g?

Comment: вы издеваетесь ?

Comment: @sonniy При таком подходе на выходе могут получаться строки, отсутствующие в исходной таблице.

Comment: @alexlz как могут получится строки которых нет ? какие ? пример ?

Comment: @sonniy Комбинацией значений нескольких строк. `max(a),max(b),max(e),max(f),max(g)` Если a = max(a) в одной строке, b = max(b) -- в другой и т.д.

Comment: @alexlz я изначально не так понял:

    отсутствующие в исходной таблице

но и оставить без обработки, данные нельзя ибо будет несколько претендентов на вывод

Comment: @sonniy А это вопрос к @green93. Возможных вариантов несколько, некоторые легко описываются на sql, некоторые -- не легко, но решать должен ТС.

Answer (score 0):

Топорно но вроде работает, правда проверял в Oracle, нет MsSQL под рукой:

```
select a,b,c,d,e,f,g from table_name group by a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

Comment: distinct по всем полям же, не ?

Comment: не, вбейте 2 запроса и проверьте результат

Comment: Вы что то путаете, результат один и тот же. То что вы написали равносильно :

    select distinct a,b,c,d,e,f,g from table_name

Comment: По всем полям я понял как:
select distinct * from table_name

Но указанный Вами вариант, да, работает так же.